# Issue with dynamic button in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm new in android development and am facing issue with my test code . I want add buttons when click on the "+" button. Its getting added but position is not correct. I want to add the new button after edit text which is defined through XML.Am adding xml and my code. Thnks.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#EBE7E4" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/content_new" />
</RelativeLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name of label" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
    android:text="Save &amp; Continue" />
```

```
private Spinner spinner;
ImageButton btnAddNew;
public static int MY_BUTTON = 2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_steps);        
    btnAddNew =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);        
    addItemsOnSpinner();

    btnAddNew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
              Log.w("ANDROID DYNAMIC VIEWS:", "View Id: " + MY_BUTTON);
            LinearLayout rAlign = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lId);
            Button newPass = new Button(getApplicationContext());
            newPass.setText("Add LABEL");
            newPass.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            newPass.setWidth(418);
            newPass.setId(MY_BUTTON);
            //newPass.
            newPass.setOnClickListener(this);
            rAlign.addView(newPass);
            MY_BUTTON ++;

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: for that you need to create your layout dynamically

Comment: You are adding your button to rAlign (Linear layout) so you have to first align this layout below/right of edit text

Comment: @ JaiSoni hmm ok let me try :) thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i solved by changing some lines in your XML

Here is a XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#EBE7E4" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name of label" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lId"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
    android:text="Save &amp; Continue" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Nothing changed in `onCreate` function

Comment: There is a Problem in your OnCreate Function if you click that AddLabel button it will generate new Button by solve that problem you need to remove newPass.setOnClickListener(this); or if you need to do action create new listener and do what ever you want

Answer (score 0):

**-** Though this solution will not work for N nos of Button, but will work if you know how many buttons to appear in hand

**-** Use `TableRow` after `EditText`, and then after dynamically creating the buttons add them in the `TableRow`.

**-** Take care that the buttons don't pass the right side of the screen when the buttons gets more than screen can show in emulator or phone